# Tagging sports games - can we get away with just a generic [sports] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

For example, if a question is about [pro-evolution-soccer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pro-evolution-soccer), does it also need the [football](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/football) or [soccer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soccer) tag, or can we get away with a [sports](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sports) tag only?

It hasn't come up often, really because we only have [football](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/football). Which was first used for [American Football](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/818/which-nfl-american-football-simulation-games-work-under-linux), but also headed on to the [other](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2198/fifa-2009-free-kick-techniques) [football](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2244/what-tricks-are-possible-playing-pes-2010-on-a-keyboard).

I think we need [sports](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sports) or [sports-game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sports-game) anyway, just to serve as a genre not unlike [real-time-strategy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-time-strategy). We do have one existing [sport](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sport), but it's very easy to change it over. But the real question is, is this genre tag sufficient or do we think it'll be better overall to tag each sports game with the separate sports? I can see advantages to both - freeing up tags in one scenario, but grouping together different games of the same sport in the other. Most sports games are pretty obvious in their title what sport they are about, except Captain Tsubasa, which is so popular that most people know what sport it is anyway.

What are your thoughts? If we do plan to tag with the sport as well, how should we disambiguate the eternal debate on "what is football"?

Comment: I have a distinct feeling that the resolution of this question may change, due to our shift in how we handle tagging by genre.

Answer (score 1):

I think your answer about genres and the idea of a tag set for [sports](/questions/tagged/sports) is the best solution for this issue. The suggestion by alexanderpas of [sports](/questions/tagged/sports) for titles that are collections of sports is probably the best use of that tag.

There are a number of sports games that identify the sport in the title, and the ones that don't really aren't that different than, say, WoW or CoD or SC2: if you aren't familiar with the title, you probably either aren't looking for content about it (to ask or to answer) or are looking for the specific game rather than the genre.

I also think there are few questions about a sports game that can really be applied to any sports game. I suppose there are probably questions about rules of or strategies within a particular sport (that could be better answered in a Sports.SE if one existed) that might need [hockey](/questions/tagged/hockey) or [american-football](/questions/tagged/american-football), but even then, there simply aren't that many different titles within a particular sport, and how those rules and strategies are applied might well be specific to one title or one series, and are probably better tagged as the specific title that was being played when the question came up.

For example, someone might ask "What is the two-minute warning and what does it mean?" That's an American Football rule, but only in NFL football, so it wouldn't apply to EA's Arena Football or NCAA Football, and thus [american-football](/questions/tagged/american-football) doesn't apply. Rules also change in NBA basketball games at the two-minute mark, but those changes occur in each quarter rather than each half and are not the same as the NFL changes, so even [sports](/questions/tagged/sports) would be misleading.

Tagging those questions with the specific title, like [madden-10](/questions/tagged/madden-10), also resolves issues with real-world rule changes that are reflected in subsequent titles. A question like "Why am I kicking off from the 35?" will have a different answer in Madden 12 due to the changes for the 2011 season; tagging it with [american-football](/questions/tagged/american-football) or even [american-football-professional](/questions/tagged/american-football-professional) would lead to two different sets of correct answers (or three, depending on the depth of the question, to cover the earlier Madden games where kickoffs also were done from the 35 but other rules were different).

Answer (score 0):

first of all, [football](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/football) should be blocked, as even [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Football) has an article about the different types of football under that name.

> The most popular of these sports worldwide is association football, more commonly known as just "football" or "soccer". Unqualified, the word football applies to whichever form of football is the most popular in the regional context in which the word appears, including American football, Australian rules football, Canadian football, Gaelic football, rugby league, rugby union and other related games.

The solution, is, to use [soccer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soccer), [american-football](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/american-football) and [rugby](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rugby) for the respective sports.

I think we should choose to go for specific sports when a game is about one sport, and a general tag, for when it is a game with a load of sports (think wii sports resort.) or the sports genre.

Comment: The specific sport *is* football, not soccer.  At least in most of the world ;-)  (not a soccer/football fan myself, even though it's almost my patriotic duty, being German ;-)

Comment: @jae I hear you ;) dutch guy here; however, to prevent confusion, I suggested the destintion. I've added the important quote from wikipedia to my post.